# Possible to use Google Maps JavaScript API on meteor server side?

Tags: node.js, google-maps, meteor, google-maps-api-3

I am working on google map application which uses the google map version3 api. I am using in particular the utility methods in [google.maps.latLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/), such as getbounds, computeDistanceBetween, contains, fromLatLngToPoint in order to compute whether the bound lies inside or not.

I am using package [dburles/meteor-google-maps](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps) which allows me to compute some values at client side, but not at server side. I have to do some calculations on server, particularly at models. I wonder if there is a way use google map api on meteor server.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use any Node module like:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/maps
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/googlemaps
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-geocoder

etc. in your backend code in Meteor. Just make sure that it runs only for the server-side.

Of course you will need API keys for that to work.